# AVAudioPlayer makes click/pop noise when song is started/stopped

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I'm using AVAudioPlayer to play a music file. When I call `start` or `stop`, there's an audible "click" or "pop" noise. I've tried it with both mp3 and caf files, and hear it in both cases (though I don't hear it every single time). Does anyone know how to prevent these glitchy noises?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who happens upon this in the future, you have to turn the AVAudioPlayer's volume down to 0, then call `stop` ~0.5s later.

Comment: Thanks, saved my day. Note that you can also use a shorter time. Tuning down the volume 50ms before the stop worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for this info, for anyone interested, I also set a NSTimer scheduled to the audio file duration - 0.5s, to stop the clicking when the player is finished (user doesn't actually touch the stop button).

Answer (score 2):

The following tip is to just work on `stop` audio playing.

When we need to call `stop` to stop the audio playback, we can call `pause` first and followed by `stop`. That means in our custom stop method, we use `pause` and `stop` from `AVAudioPlayer` to stop the playback and also prevent the pop or the click noise.

Comment: Thank you! Yes the pause before Stop fixed the pop on stopping.  And I also used the other trick where you start the volume at 0, start the playback, and then raise the volume up to fix the pop on starting playback.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that fixed the audio issue on my side (iPhone XS/XR, iOS 13), was to use `AVQueuePlayer` instead of `AVAudioPlayer`:

```
func play() {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sound", withExtension: "wav") else {
        return
    }
    let player = AVQueuePlayer(url: url) // It was AVAudioPlayer before 
    player.volume = 1.0
    player.play()
}
```

Don't ask me why that works, but it does. `AVAudioPlayer` produces click/pop noises in our XS/XR devices. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Swift's fade in function.  I did not notice a pop on the stop, but I am pretty certain you could something similar to fix that too. Here is an example of how I implemented it.  Note, in my viewDidLoad I am also initializing some audio settings.  You may have to experiment with the fade timing to perfect your audio.

```
   import UIKit
    import AVKit

    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        initializeAudioPlayer()
    }

func initializeAudioPlayer() {
    do {
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try session.setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}


func soundButtonTapped() {

        let tuneURL:URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "left", withExtension: "wav")!
        playSound(tuneURL, withDelay: 0.1)
}




func playSound(_ tuneURL: URL, withDelay delay:Double) {

    do {

        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: tuneURL, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3) //old version of Swift AVFileType.mp3.rawValue
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: tuneURL, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEG4)
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: tuneURL, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeWAVE)

        audioPlayer.volume = 0.0 //start it at zero
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1  //loop on
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
        audioPlayer.setVolume(1, fadeDuration: delay) //fade in with delay

    } catch let error as NSError {
        NSLog(error.description)
    }
}
```